# How to allow popups when url loads if it is NOT a physical click by the user in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to allow popups when site loads and if the root cause of an event is NOT a physical click by the user, then it's getting blocked. Any help?

My code:

```
$("#buttonBtn").on('click',function(){
    openpopup('temp'+id)
});

$("#buttonBtn").trigger('click');
```

Comment: Sounds to me like this is the users browser kicking in. Any popup that is initiated without explicit user interaction could easily be seen as "unwanted" so the browser (or any other adblock addon) will prevent it from being displayed.

Comment: Ya i know browser will prevent it.. any help..

Comment: Well it really is a desired behavior. If you were able to bypass it then it wouldn't be very effective to prevent unwanted popups, would it?

Comment: Browser will NOT prevent it, if it is some JS/jQuery popup (some `<div>` that pops up). IF he pop up window, then it would be prevented.

Comment: @cer - I'm fairly sure we are talking about a new window as a popup and not a plugin modal dialog or something similar - those are not affected by these security measures.

Comment: yes Lix you are correct... openpopup function will open iframe(window.open)... i don't have any control over this openpopup function..and if i do any physical click on button this popup works..

Comment: I want to call openpopup function when url loads... browser is blocking my popup at start..

Comment: You will have to figure out another way of doing this, because this sort of behavior is blocked *by design* to disallow popups.

Comment: any other way please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

With this, if you explicitly click, popup appears. If user comes to this button via keyboard and press Enter or something, I guess this would not be triggered.

```
$("#buttonBtn").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    // some job you will do if clicked, for example, open popup

});
```

[Great example here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: openpopup function will open iframe(window.open)... i don't have any control over this openpopup function..and any physical click on button this popup works.... but i need when url loads i want to call openpopup function at start..

Comment: Oh I get it right now, I misunderstood your question. I don't know how to do this, sorry. I'll erase my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally open popups by using `window.open`. However, most browsers have built-in popup blocker where the user will be notified about a popup and will be asked if he really wants to show it.

The MDN has an informative article about `window.open`. It also gives some information about popup blockers:

> How can I tell when my window was blocked by a popup blocker?
>
> With the
>   built-in popup blockers of Mozilla/Firefox and Internet Explorer 6
>   SP2, you have to check the return value of window.open(): it will be
>   null if the window wasn't allowed to open. However, for most other
>   popup blockers, there is no reliable way.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open